# What's the difference between a GLX visual and a FBconfig?

Tags: linux, opengl, x11

I'm learning OpenGL under X11 with xcb and I'm having a hard time figuring out the difference between visuals and fbconfigs (the ones you find in `glxinfo`)

As far as I could see a visual is a set of properties related to depth buffer, stencil buffer, framebuffer, etc.. what's the difference with fbconfigs and why would one be preferable to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **X Window System**  a **Visual** encapsulates the color mapping (color type, color depth) for a *Display*. The same Display can be configured with different Visuals.

When OpenGL was born, about a decade after X System, a structure `XVisualInfo` was created in the OGL part, not in the X System. This new structure extended the `Visual`  type by adding more features, such as ancillary buffers, double buffer, and stereo. This `XVisualInfo` was used to create the gl-context.

In 1998 the GLX 1.3 specification (find it at [Khronos page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php)), added more features, notably `GLXPbuffer` for off-screen rendering, but easier than `GLXPixmap`. Also added were transparency, multi-sampling, and samples buffers. The configuration for the `GLXDrawable` (Window or GLXPixmap, or now also GLXWindow and GLXPbuffer) was going too different from the Visual abilities, and so `GLXFBConfig` was introduced.

The current GLX 1.4 specification allows, for backwards compatibility reasons and if you don't use GLX>1.2 features, the use of `XVisualInfo`. But the prefered way of creating a context is by GLXFBConfig.

Notice that rendering to a GLXPbuffer does not use a X Visual. Notice also that using [Framebuffer objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) since OGL 3.0 makes obsolete the use of GLXPbuffer.

Comment: You wrote "a structure XVisualInfo was created in the OGL part, not in the X System". How is it then that `XVisualInfo` is part of the Xlib and can be found in its documentation as well as the header files? From what I know, `XVisualInfo` is a client-side wrapper adound the "opaque" (i.e. implementation-defined) `Visual` structure. It doesn't have much to do with OpenGL, you can use it indepdendently, just in ordinary Xlib code.

Comment: You also wrote "This new structure extended the Visual type by adding more features, such as ancillary buffers, double buffer, and stereo."  I don't see any such things in the `XVisualInfo` structure. The only fields it adds around the `Visual` is: `colormap_size`, `bits_per_rgb`, `red_mask`, `green_mask`, `blue_mask`, `class`, `depth` and `screen`. Things to deal with the partition of the pixel into separate RGB components and color mapping. There's nothing about double buffering, or any other non-color buffers. Those things are parts of `FBConfig`, which is the *actual* extension of Visuals.

Comment: @SasQ OpenGL in Linux is **an extension** to X Window System. That 'extension' is what I refer as 'OGL part' and is named 'GLX'. Read first 2 pages of [GLX 1.2 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glx1.2.ps). And *figure 1* to see how Xlib is in OGL part.

Comment: I know GLX pretty thoroughly, and that makes me dubious about what you wrote, because according to the specs, it doesn't hold any water. OpenGL is not an "extension to X window system" – it is a platform-independent API specification, with different implementations on different platforms. On Linux, the X protocol is extended by GLX to introduce support for OpenGL, however, the actual implementation of these GL calls is usually a separate library, not supplied with Xlib (you link with -lGL, don't you?). For example, it could be MESA or some device driver from nVidia or ATI.

Comment: However, this is irrelevant to my previous objections. `XVisualInfo` is defined in `X11/Xutil.h`, which has nothing to do with OpenGL or GLX whatsoever, and it was there before GLX, so it *cannot* have anything to do with double-buffering, stereo, or anciliary buffers. It only deals with X Visuals. GLX associates its `GLXFBConfig` structure with Visuals that support OpenGL rendering, but keeps them separate from `XVisualInfo`. That's why there can be Visuals that *do not* support OpenGL rendering.

Answer (score 6):

The *visual* is a concept of X11 itself. It describes the color encoding properties. A particular X11 server my supper a set of different visuals, and and X11 client (graphical application) may choose one that is best suited for it's use case. Every X11 window is created with respect to one visual. See [the documentation about X11 visual types](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/visual-types.html) for details.

On an X11 server with the glX extension, there are a couple of such visuals which provide hardware accelerated rendering via OpenGL. Before you can create a X11 window which you're going to use for GL rendering, you need to query a suitable visual. In traditional glX, you would use for example [`glXChooseVisual`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glXChooseVisual.xml) to do that.

A `GLXFBConfig` on the other hand is a entity that is only relevant for GLX itself, the classical X server does not know anything about it. GLXFBconfigs can be used to create off-screen rendering buffers called [P-Buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/P-buffer) (which are kind of obsolete nowadays, though).

One could classify FBConfigs into two groups:

1. GLXFBConfigs which you can use to create a X11 window with. In this case, the FBConfig refers to some X11 visual ID, and you can use [`glXGetVisualFromFBConfig`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glXGetVisualFromFBConfig.xml) to query that.
2. GLXFBConfigs which can solely be used for off-screen rendering. There is no associated visual ID, so you cannot use these to create X11 windows with.

FBConfigs provide a newer and more flexible interface via [`glxChooseFBConfig`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml), so it is preferable alwyas to use the FBConfig API, even if you want an off-screen window.

What a typical GL implementation will do is to provide an FBconfig for each visual type it is supporting, so you should find those twice in the `glxinfo` output: as the actual visuals, and as more or less identical fbconfigs. Additionally, it will offer some more fbconfigs with formats which would be untypical for X11 windows (like more than 32bit color depth).